# Approximate $e^{-\frac{2}{3e}}$ by rational number

Tags: calculus

Approximate $e^{-\frac{2}{3e}}$ by rational number with 5% accuracy.
I'm trying using taylor series but irrationality of argument...

Comment: Hint: First get a great approximation for $\frac{2}{3e}$.

Comment: Hint: a "great" approximation of $\frac{1}{e}$ is $\frac{1}{e}\approx 1-1+\frac12-\frac16+\frac{1}{24}=\frac38$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\frac{2}{3e}<\frac{1}{4}$ and 
$$ e^{-x}-1+x \leq \frac{1}{2}x^2 $$
over $[0,1]$, the absolute error when estimating $e^{-\frac{2}{3e}}$ with $1-\frac{2}{3e}$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{32}$.

Hence we just need a reasonable estimation for $e^{-1}$, like:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{5}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} = \frac{11}{30}, $$
whose absolute error is less than $\frac{1}{5!}=\frac{1}{120}$, to state:
$$ e^{-\frac{2}{3e}}\approx 1-\frac{22}{90} = \color{red}{\frac{34}{45}}.$$
The relative error is around $3.5\%$. Other possible approaches are to approximate just $e^{-\frac{1}{4}}$ or to use $e^{-x}\approx\frac{1}{1+x}$. An even better approximation is given by $\color{blue}{\frac{18}{23}}$, that is a convergent of the continued fraction, with a relative error around $0.1\%$.

Comment: Presumably, since this is an effort to not use a calculator, we'd also want to show that $\frac{2}{3e}<\frac{1}{4}$, that is, showing $3e>8$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: for such a task, it is sufficient to notice that $$ e>\sum_{k=0}^{3}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{8}{3}.$$

Comment: Sure, just wanted it for completeness :)

Comment: The "simplest" such rational number is $\frac{3}{4}$. Obviously, not as good an approximation.